# Angularjs $scope array object rearrange

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a json array which I assign to a **$scope** object to display at the front-end. I want to rearrange this array on the basis of given id.
This is how my initial array looks like.

```
$scope.listData = [{
id: 1,
name: adam,
title: testing title,
description: testing description
},
{
id: 2,
name: zampa,
title: testing title,
description: testing description
},
{
id: 3,
name: Aaron,
title: testing title,
description: testing description
}]
```

For rearrangement, For Instance if given id is 3, rearrangement of records should be like 3,1,2.

I have tried using angular.forEach loop, but did not succeed.

Comment: So you just want to move the item with the given ID to the start of the array?

Comment: correct. just rearrangement, no remove no deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift):

```
function moveToFront(id, array) {
  const i = array.findIndex(v => v.id === id);

  array.unshift(...array.splice(i, 1));
}
```

---

Complete snippet:

```js
const listData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'adam',
    title: 'testing title',
    description: 'testing description'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'zampa',
    title: 'testing title',
    description: 'testing description'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Aaron',
    title: 'testing title',
    description: 'testing description'
  }
];

function moveToFront(id, array) {
  const i = array.findIndex(v => v.id === id);
  
  array.unshift(...array.splice(i, 1));
}

moveToFront(3, listData);

console.log(listData);
```

Comment: unshift function just returning a number, not the array.

Comment: @ShaurBinTalib The function modifies the array in place (as per the question's requirements). There's no need to return anything.

Comment: yes I got it. Its working perfectly as per my requirement. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

//Assuming it is sorted by id initially, starting frm one

```
listData.splice(0, 0, listData.splice(id - 1, 1)[0]);
```

Comment: returns empty array

Comment: listData itself changed

Comment: This will only work once though. The second time the order of IDs will be different.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. However, I got my answer. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: ya correct, but then, idea of no deletion and only rearrangement is not there right, there is always new copy of array, anyway prob is solved